# How to remove repeatedly failing driver update in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I recently upgraded a laptop from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10 Pro. Since then, an Intel graphics driver update pulled down by Windows Update keeps trying and failing to install.

Is there a way I can remove this update?

I've tried https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930 - it doesn't list any updates available in my case, probably because it hasn't installed successfully.

I've also tried clearing C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download.

It's a big nuisance to have it keep prompting me about the failed update every time I use the computer.

NOTE: I don't want to disable ALL driver updates, I just want a way to remove one that keeps failing to install. This may also apply to cherry-picking a non-driver failing update, but I'm not sure (as I said, KB3073930 does not help in my case)

Comment: @Moab - Maybe? However, the solution to that question does not solve this issue. I don't think Windows Update in Windows 10 respects the old Windows 7 setting on auto-downloading drivers, and nothing so far seems to purge this failed / pending reinstall update.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is about stopping all driver updates while this question is about stopping only a selected one.

Answer (score -2):

This has happened to me previously, What i ended up doing was reinstalling the os, But you can also disable the windows updates if you really have to, Search "How to disable windows updates" and it will come up with a reg edit program (i think) that will disable them. Hope this helps

Comment: Not an answer. In terms of both acceptable form and actually the tip you included is misleading as it deals with different issue.